Making 1353 using Four fours
As the title says, the goal for this puzzle is making 1353 out of simply 4, 4, 4 and 4. Concatenation is not allowed. Here are all of the allowed operators.

Addition (+), Subtraction and negatives (-), Multiplication (*), Division (/)
Roots (√), Exponents (^)
Decimals and repeating decimals (.)
Percentages (%), which divide a number by 100

Hint: It has something to do with two thirds.
You may use up to 20 operators. Good luck!

So can we use parentheses?

Here is how you do it:

$$\frac{4/.\bar4％+\sqrt{4}}{\sqrt{.\bar4}}$$


I made it a little nicer aesthetically

?what is the overbar meant to do

@paul23 Repeating decimal .44444444444444….
